# inclusion of jquery file is giving error jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property ‘indexOf’ of undefined TypeError:

Tags: jquery, css

Whenever I include jquery file in my project, I get this error

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property ‘indexOf’ of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property ‘indexOf’ of undefined..

I am using materialize css framework. I have included script files as under:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/materialize.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jQuery.scrollSpeed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try using lower version of Jquery and check

Comment: yup that worked...i wonder why

Comment: There may be some functions depreciated in higher versions of jquery

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `indexOf` inside any loop ? then please check this link [unDefined TypeError Cannot read property ‘indexOf’ of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911859/cannot-read-property-indexof-of-undefined)

Comment: i am not using indexOf